# Optuna returns the last value, not the best one for one trial

Tags: optuna

I'm using Optuna. Imagine these are the value for "1 trial" with "5 epochs or steps":

Epoch 0: 18 - Epoch 1: 32 - Epoch 2: 14 - Epoch 3: 28 - Epoch 4: 25

I expect Optuna to return 14 as the value for this trial but it gives me 25 (value of the last epoch). I want optuna to return the best intermediate value as the final value, not the last one. Any explanation, as well as the solution to solve the problem, will be appreciated.

P.s: I am talking about just one trial, not a study.

Answer (score 1):

How about saving all intermediate values in a list and getting the maximum/minimum value from it?

The following is an pseudo code of this approach:

```py
def objective(trial):
    ...
    accuracies = []
    for i in range(N_ITERATIONS):
        accuracy = n_correct / N_VALID_EXAMPLES
        accuracies.append(accuracy)
    return max(accuracies)
```

You can find a working example in [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/144xB5ogU1_6Sq37rzCt4-Y67LruxJNJE#scrollTo=FaKrbDHqphaP).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed my code but I have another question. The sampler would consider the "max(accuracies)" to sample new parameters, am I right? But what about the Pruner?